# Crystal Reports Summary not showing in Page Footer but in Report Footer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, report

I have a simple Select * from Table that i want to show on crystal report.
I want to have a summary of records on each page as well as in the report footer too. But when i follow these steps, i can't see any Page Footer in the drop down list of 'Summary Location'.

Right Click -> Insert -> Summary -> Summary Location. **Only Report Footer is shown**

Anyone have had a similiar problem ?

Comment: What sort of summary of records do you want - a count of records on the page? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Updated) Unfortunately, you can't put summary items into page headers / footers in Crystal.

To get round this, you need to use Crystal variables inside Crystal formulas.

To set up running totals of columns on the page:

(1) Create a formula (called something like `initiate`) to set the totals to 0, with the following code:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
global numberVar tot1;
global numberVar tot2;
tot1 := 0;
tot2 := 0
```

Include one variable for each column you wish to sum. Add this formula to your page header section, and set it to be suppressed.

(2) Create a formula (called something like `iterate`) to add column values to each total, similar to the following code:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
global numbervar tot1;
global numbervar tot2;
tot1 := tot1+{table.Field1};
tot2 := tot2+{table.Field2}
```

Add this formula to your details section, and set it to be suppressed.

(3) Create a formula (called something like `display1`, `display2`, etc) for **each** total to display the total, similar to the following code:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
global numbervar tot1;
tot1 := tot1+0
```

Add these formulas to your page footer section (not set to be suppressed).

Comment: Mark thanks, but i want to get total of few columns that are displayed in the details section. In the above mentioned formulas, where do i put the column or field name?

Comment: @AtharAnis: Inside the `iterate` formula - I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much. It did the trick. I am surprised why Crystal Reports doesn't give it as a built-in option